# Python Win32 for Sending Emails - Failure to Send Emails within For Loop: "Item has been moved or deleted"

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32

A function is created to send emails. The function takes in a pandas dataframe of email recipients by name and their corresponding addresses. Each recipient is looped through, sending an email to each using the win32com.client package using Outlook:

```
def send_emails(recipient_data):
    """

    Args:
        recipient_data: A pandas dataframe containing a table of email recipients and email addresses.

    Returns:
        None

    """

    ol = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')  # Open the client to connect to Outlook.
    ol_mail_item = 0x0  # size of the new email in python's memory
    new_mail = ol.CreateItem(ol_mail_item)

    new_mail.Subject = "New Pond Regent"
    body_raw = "As I'm sure you are all aware. Mr Goldeneye has recently taken the post of Regent of The Pond."

    recipient_column = "Recipients"
    recipients = recipient_data[recipient_column].tolist()

    i = 1
    for recipient in recipients:
        email_column = "duck_addresses"
        email_address = recipient_data[email_column].loc[recipient_data[recipient_column] == recipient].values[0]
        new_mail.To = email_address
        if "@" in str(email_address):
            new_mail.Body = body_raw
            new_mail.Send()
            i += 1
        else:
            print(f"No email address given for {recipient}. No email will be prepared.")
```

Test data is created and the function called:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    ducks = ['Mr Mandarin', 'Lord Gadwall', 'Sir Shoveller', 'Earl Goosander', 'Lady Eider']
    duck_addresses = ['crest@mandarin.com', 'paddle@gadwall.com', 'dive@shovel.co.uk', 'peck@goosander.ac.uk',
                      'dabble@eider.org']
    duck_data = {"Recipients": ducks, "duck_addresses": duck_addresses}
    user_email_input = pd.DataFrame(duck_data)
    send_emails(user_email_input)
```

Only the first email sends. After going through the first iteration of the for loop within the send_emails function, an error is returned by the win32 package:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The item has been moved or deleted.', None, 0, -2147221238), None)
```

What is the error in the code or the approach?